# LibGDX boolean values turn to false after minimizing window?

Tags: libgdx, lwjgl

I have a Java class which is a singleton which stores a boolean variable:

```
public boolean paused;
```

So basically I use it when the game is paused and to set it to `true` or `false`. I use this (to call the pause variable):

```
public static DataVariables getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}
```

Everything works fine, the game stops when I use the variable, but I noticed that after minimizing my window the value suddenly turns to `false` and the game behaves as if it hasn't been stopped. Can anyone tell why this is?

Comment: Figured it out, i had in the where i implement the Screen class put the variable to true in resume()